# How to check if an item exists in local storage without having the full path available?

Tags: javascript, regex, path

I need to check wether a file exists in localStorage.

The filepath consists of

```
id.version
```

and I only have a the `id` value to test, which will be a 10 character string followed by the version which is of random length.

I'm used to checking for file existence server side using Coldfusion, where I can do something like this:

```
fileExists(expandPath(../some/path/to/a/file.*) )
```

where `*` would be any character.

**Question**:
Is something like this possible using regex, so I could test whether a file that contains the `id` parameter and any number of characters following the id exist? I don't need to retrieve the file itself, just know if there is at least one with matching `id` in the path.

Thanks for help!

Comment: I didn’t know *files* could exist in a localStorage?

Comment: hm. I should say items at specified locations.

Comment: @David - they can't, but strings can and most files can be turned into a string with the HTML5 FileReader API, but I'm guessing the OP is misunderstanding.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can iterate over each localstorage item and get the key with the `.key()` method and check if that contains the id string etc. or use a regex to do something similar, Figuring out how to check the value and not the key, if that's where the ID resides, should be trivial :

```
for (var i = 0; i < localStorage.length; i++){
    if ( localStorage.key(i).indexOf(id) != -1 ) {
        var item = localStorage.getItem(localStorage.key(i));
    }
}
```

Comment: @frequent - I'm not sure I understand if you're looking for the key or the value, and what you want to compare that against, but the example at least shows how to get both the key and the value, and then it's up to you I guess to figure out what you want?